# How to change text of specific line in multiline textbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox, multiline

I have a multi-line text box in my WPF project, and I want to change the specified line text.  I used to do this easily in Win form, but there is no Lines option in WPF Text box.  For example, I used to do this in Windows Form:

```
Dim lines As String() = VTextBox1.Lines

            lines(Specific Line Number) = "This is a test."

            VTextBox1.Lines = lines
```

But this piece of cod, not working in WPF textbox.

> Do I have any chance that I do this in the WPF textbox?

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change text of specific line in multiline textbox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74994336/how-to-change-text-of-specific-line-in-multiline-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: @Florian No. I have raised this question.

Comment: You raised this question four times. I flagged three of them that an admin deletes it. And this comment will come automatically cause of flagging the question. Please delete three of these four questions.

Comment: @Florian I am very sorry, this is because the internet in my country is very bad at the moment and all the people of my country are under pressure. I am asking this question from Iran. This is a problem with my internet. Thank you for letting me know about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it "manually" by manipulating the string yourself:

```vb
Dim lines As String() = VTextBox1.Text.Split(vbLf)

Dim lineNumber As Integer = 5
If lines.Length > lineNumber Then
    lines(lineNumber) = "This is a test."
    VTextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbLf, lines)
End If
```

Comment: Dear Olivier Jacot-Descombes This was a great method, exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for your help